# Is it possible to expose a Spring MVC controller within a simple application context that is NOT a web application with a web.xml?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to expose a Spring MVC controller in an application that will NOT be deployed in a web container like Tomcat.  Is this possible?  If so, can you please provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot has [embedded servlet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html) containers. This enables you to launch apps by executing a jar, instead of deployment to servlet container